# PHP function preg_replace doesn't work

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm checking if text contains email pattern but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.
this is my code:

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/";
$replacement = "**************";
$_POST['description'] = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $_POST['description']);
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" definetly does **not** help anybody.

Comment: What's the value `$_POST['description']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about removing anchors:

```
$pattern = "/\b[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}\b/";
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you dont want preg_replace you can used this function i found online

```
function isValidEmail($address) {
    if (filter_var($address,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)==FALSE) {
        return false;
    }
    /* explode out local and domain */
    list($local,$domain)=explode('@',$address);

    $localLength=strlen($local);
    $domainLength=strlen($domain);

    return (
        /* check for proper lengths */
        ($localLength>0 && $localLength<65) &&
        ($domainLength>3 && $domainLength<256) &&
        (
            checkdnsrr($domain,'MX') ||
            checkdnsrr($domain,'A')
        )
    );
}
```

[Ref](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/76404-how-to-validate-email-address-using-preg-replace/)

Comment: It works but you have to extract the address from the input string before.